# I get a ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT for the web and cant connect via SSH to a server

Tags: linux, ssh, connection, web

Was in the middle of working on a website on a linode server when suddenly it went offline. Trying to connect via the web I get:

```
 This site can’t be reached

 xxxxx.com took too long to respond.

 Search Google for xxxxx

 ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

This is from every browser , including in incognito mode.
I cannot connect via SSH either. Also a PING results in a time out.
From the Linode Provider: The status of the system is boot and I can login via a web interface.

On the system itself:

```
skunkworks:~$ networkctl list
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.

IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP 
  1 lo               loopback           n/a         unmanaged
  2 dummy0           ether              n/a         unmanaged
  3 eth0             ether              n/a         unmanaged
  4 teql0            void               n/a         unmanaged
  5 tunl0            tunnel             n/a         unmanaged
  6 gre0             ipgre              n/a         unmanaged
  7 gretap0          ether              n/a         unmanaged
  8 erspan0          ether              n/a         unmanaged
  9 ip_vti0          tunnel             n/a         unmanaged
 10 ip6_vti0         tunnel6            n/a         unmanaged
 11 sit0             sit                n/a         unmanaged
 12 ip6tnl0          tunnel6            n/a         unmanaged
 13 ip6gre0          n/a                n/a         unmanaged
 14 docker0          ether              n/a         unmanaged

14 links listed.
@skunkworks:~$
```

I see this! So I try:

```
@skunkworks:~$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
@skunkworks:~$ networkctl list
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged
  2 dummy0           ether              off         unmanaged
  3 eth0             ether              off         unmanaged
  4 teql0            void               off         unmanaged
  5 tunl0            tunnel             off         unmanaged
  6 gre0             ipgre              off         unmanaged
  7 gretap0          ether              off         unmanaged
  8 erspan0          ether              off         unmanaged
  9 ip_vti0          tunnel             off         unmanaged
 10 ip6_vti0         tunnel6            off         unmanaged
 11 sit0             sit                off         unmanaged
 12 ip6tnl0          tunnel6            off         unmanaged
 13 ip6gre0          n/a                off         unmanaged
 14 docker0          ether              no-carrier  unmanaged

14 links listed.
```

A little better but still no website or SSH! What happened and any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It might have reverted your firewall settings. Check it:

```
/sbin/iptables -t filter -L -n
```